# How to include ambient module declarations inside another ambient module?

Tags: typescript

I have an ambient `.d.ts` module which directly depends on Immutable:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts" />
import I = require('immutable');

declare module 'morearty' {
}
```

But referencing the immutable directly is prohibited by the compiler with this error:

`error TS2435: Ambient external modules cannot be nested in other modules.`

How could I include the Immutable ambient declarations inside my ambient module? I tried to import  immutable from another proxy module but with no luck.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Ambient external modules cannot be nested in other modules.

Using an `import` or `export` at the root of a file creates a *file module*. That explains the error *nested module*.

Fix: Import *inside* and *not* at the root of the file:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts" />

declare module 'morearty' {
    import I = require('immutable');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a similar issue with a custom ambient module and was pulling my hair out!

Comment: do we need to use the reference path ?