# Ambient declaration with an imported type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a declaration file in my TypeScript project like so:

```
// myapp.d.ts
declare namespace MyApp {
  interface MyThing {
    prop1: string
    prop2: number
  }
}
```

This works great and I can use this namespace anywhere in my project without having to import it.

I now need to import a type from a 3rd party module and use it in my ambient declaration:

```
// myapp.d.ts
import {SomeType} from 'module'

declare namespace MyApp {
  interface MyThing {
    prop1: string
    prop2: number
    prop3: SomeType
  }
}
```

The compiler now complains that it can't find namespace 'MyApp', presumably because the import prevents it from being ambient.

Is there some easy way to retain the ambient-ness of the declaration whilst utilising 3rd-party types?

Comment: @RomanStarkov This is not possible for any arbitrary library, do you have a specific one in mind ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Let's say `luxon`, it comes with typings and looks just like this sample code here - `import { DateTime } from 'luxon'`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It has become easier in TypeScript 2.9 by using [import() a type](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/16/announcing-typescript-2-9-rc/) but it's also possible in earlier versions of TypeScript.

The following file is a *script*. Things declared in a script are added to the *global scope*. This is why you can use `MyApp.MyThing` without importing it.

```
// myapp.d.ts
declare namespace MyApp {
  interface MyThing {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
  }
}
```

Scripts are limited in that they cannot import anything; when you add an `import`, the script becomes a *module*. I think it's weird to say the least, but it is what it is. What matters is that things defined in a *module* are scoped to that module, and are not added to the global scope.

However, modules *can* add declarations to the global scope too, by putting them inside `global`:

```
// myapp.d.ts
import {SomeType} from 'module';

declare global {
  namespace MyApp {
    interface MyThing {
      prop1: string;
      prop2: number;
      prop3: SomeType;
    }
  }
}
```

This file is a *module*, but it adds a declaration of `MyApp.MyThing` to the global scope, so you can still use `MyApp.MyThing` in other TypeScript code without importing it.

Note that using the `.d.ts` extension has nothing to do with you being able to access the interface without importing it. Both of the above files could have been `.ts` files and would still behave exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been looking for this  solution for over an hour now. Why it's so hard to integrate with an environment that adds symbols to the global scope but can't be imported using regular modules is beyond me, especially as it seems to be such a common requirement...

Comment: wrapping it in `global` really needs to be more well known. This is a very common case and so many answers neglect to mention this simple fix.

Comment: Does the 2.9 feature somehow allow to declare everything from an imported module definition, that has external module format, as global  (e.g. all types, interfaces, variables)?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1000 times. I've been tying myself in knots.

Comment: this would still require importing myapp.d.ts somewhere for the global augmentation to work ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 No, the point of an "ambient declaration" is that it doesn't need importing. It's "ambient", or, all around you all the time.

Comment: @erike in the current example, the myapp.d.ts file is a module not an ambient declaration, so you would have to import it somewhere for the global augmentation to work ?

Comment: It may be a module, but it is informing TypeScript via `declare` and `global` that node/the browser **does in fact** have this stuff as a global object. `declare` in TypeScript means, we aren't going to implement this, but we are informing you that this is a thing. Wherever I refer to these types, simply assume they exist. If you look at the `"compilerOptions": { "lib": [ ... ] }` section of `tsconfig.json`, those are how TypeScript lets you select which built-in libraries (ambient declarations) it must assume exist. This *has* to work or you could never use things like `window` or `global`.

Comment: Is it possible to use `/// <reference ... />` somehow?

Answer (score 31):

Since TS 2.9 this is possible with `import()`:

```js
// myapp.d.ts
declare type SomeType = import('module').SomeType;
declare type SomeDefaultType = import('module-with-default-export').default;


declare namespace MyApp {
  interface MyThing {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop3: SomeType | SomeDefaultType;
  }
}
```

Comment: `declare type Foo = import('someModule').default` gives me an error , even though `"someModule"` defines a default export: "Namespace 'SomeModule' has no exported member 'default'".

Comment: Any idea how to make this work when it's an interface you want to import?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. As you already figured out this only works with internal code, e.g. without external dependencies. You should either go with exporting your namespace, or go for export of classes and use ES6 modules. But both will result in you requiring to `import` your stuff. Something that you're trying to avoid, as I believe.

Personally, I find it more comforting to actually use imports (even internals) throughout the code. This for the simple reason that when opening a specific file (class), all its dependencies are immediately visible.

A thorough example was already addressed in the question ["How to use namespaces with import in TypeScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37572180/1039247).

Note for others: the "namespace being available internally" is also the reason why I'm not considering this a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but this is the correct way to handle it and still be able to e.g. define generic modules, not just named namespaces:
[(original answer this is based on)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955140/how-to-include-ambient-module-declarations-inside-another-ambient-module)

```
// myapp.d.ts

declare namespace MyApp {
  import {SomeType} from 'module'
  interface MyThing {
    prop1: string
    prop2: number
    prop3: SomeType
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. At least anymore with Typescript 3.8/3.9. It will give you an error `Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a global ambient variable created by electron for the API to interact with the node process. I needed to define an interface with a property type that referenced a ***class*** from a third-party dependency rather than a type/interface.

The TS 2.9 import() syntax worked for me when using a type/interface, but not a class. Specifically I am trying to use rsjx.Observable in my interface. I was able to find a way to handle this that I haven't seen mentioned anywhere. I hope it can help someone else.

You can combine module + ambient by making a module with types you want to export, then use the TS 2.9 import() syntax to pull that into an ambient declaration.

```
// types/electronAPI.ts
import { IpcRendererEvent } from 'electron'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

export type ThingStatus = 'on' | 'off'

export interface MyElectronAPI {
  thingObservable: Observable<[IpcRendererEvent, ThingStatus]>
}
```

```
// types/global.d.ts
declare type MyElectronAPI = import('./electronAPI').MyElectronAPI

const electronAPI: MyElectronAPI
```

```
// someFile.tsx

// I get all my types :)
elecronAPI.thingObservable.subscribe(([_e, status]) => { ... } )
```